# Does the sum $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \left( 1-\frac{\ln(n)}{n} \right)^{n}$ converge or diverge?

Tags: calculus

Does the infinite sum $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \left( 1-\frac{\ln(n)}{n} \right)^{n}$ converge or diverge? I've applied root, ratio and Gauss's test but it didn't help.

Comment: What tests do you know to check for convergence? Have you tried applying them?

Comment: I know root,  ratio and Gauss's test but i couldn't figure our how to apply them here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$\begin{split}
\left( 1 - \frac{\ln n}n\right)^n &= \exp\left(n\left(\ln\left(1-\frac {\ln n}n\right)\right)\right)\\
&= \exp\left(n\left(-\frac {\ln n}n +\mathcal O\left(\frac{\ln n}n\right)^2\right)\right)\\
&=\exp\left(-\ln n +\mathcal O\left (\frac{(\ln n)^2}n\right)\right)\\
&=\frac 1 n\exp\left( \mathcal O\left (\frac{(\ln n)^2}n\right)\right)\\
&=\frac 1 n +\mathcal O\left(\frac{\ln n}n\right)^2
\end{split}$$
The sum of the first terms diverges (Harmonic series) while the sum of the second terms converges. Therefore the whole series diverges.

Comment: Very interesting method indeed. Could you explain what is happening on transition from first line to second line, where logarithm gets replaced by sum of logarithm and O ? I am assuming Taylor expansion?

Comment: Excatly. It's the Taylor expansion of $\ln(1-x)=-x+O(x^2)$.

Answer (score 4):

Here is another method (a bit rough, though).

Using the approximation
$$(1-x)^{1/x} \sim e^{-1} \ \ \ \ \mathrm{as } \ x \to 0^+$$
you have
$$\left( 1- \frac{\ln n}{n}\right)^n = \left( \left( 1- \frac{\ln n}{n}\right)^{\frac{ n}{\ln n}} \right)^{\ln n} \sim (e^{-1})^{\ln n} = \frac{1}{n}$$

This shows that the series has the same behaviour of the harmonic series $\sum(1/n)$, which is divergent.

Comment: That's a cool method! Thank you